# What would be the ideal PostgreSQL data type for storing English phrases?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

This may be a silly question, but I was wondering if should I use VARCHAR(n) or TEXT for a column that holds English phrases. The reason I'm not sure is because I don't know the maximum length, some phrases can contain up to 15 words or more. I suppose VARCHAR(500) would work well but I was also thinking on the worst case scenario. I read that there is no performance difference between TEXT and VARCHAR(n) in PostgreSQL. Should I go for TEXT in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text has no limit so it could be a correct choice, and you're right about performance: this is the postgres documentation:

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs and slower sorting. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

but you have to know that it isn't standard SQL.